# Arranging $8\times 8$ square so that every $2\times 2$ square satisfy $|ab-cd|=1$.

Tags: combinatorics

Is it possible to arrange an $8\times 8$ square with numbers $1,2,\ldots,64$ once each so that for every $2\times 2$ square, if the numbers on one diagonal is $a,b$ and the other diagonal $c,d$, then $|ab-cd|=1$?

The condition $|ab-cd|=1$ means that one of $ab$ and $cd$ is odd and the other even. So there are two odd numbers in one diagonal and at least one even number in the other diagonal. But we have an equal number of odd and even numbers to fill in.

Comment: Have you tried it for smaller values of $8$?  It doesn't work for the numbers $1,2,3,4$ in a $2\times2$ square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With that condition, two numbers $a,d$ in the same line can never both be even, since otherwise you could simply take the two numbers $b,c$ of any line in the same rows as $a,d$, and $|ab-cd|$ would be even, thus not $1$.

So you can only put one even number by line, thus at most $8$ even numbers in total, which means you can't put all numbers from $1$ to $64$.

Comment: It is possible that by $2\times2$ square, the OP does _not_ mean a $2\times2$ minor matrix. So it would actually have to be a contiguous $2\times2$ square. That just means that you can't have two even numbers _next_ to one another.

Comment: Arthur is right

Comment: ah ok, sorry for the misunderstanding.